# Is it possible to find out if some list is fixed size or not?

Tags: java

Is it possible to find out if some a list is fixed size or not?
I mean, for example this code:

```
String[] arr = {"a", "b"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

returns fixed size `List` backed by an array. But is it possible to understand programmatically if `List` is fixed-size or not without trying to add/remove elements and catching the exception? For example:

```
try {
    list.add("c");
}
catch(UnsupportedOperationException e) {
    // Fixed-size?
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use the exception?

Comment: @RC. He didn't say he couldn't but it's not ideal if there's another way to do it. Exceptions are slow and for exceptional conditions.

Comment: Close voter, please explain how this is unclear. I understand perfectly well what he's asking.

Comment: nice first question! But please show us what you've tried so far(Don't worry I'm not the close voter, I'm an up-voter)

Comment: can you just use `if(list.size() > 0) {`?

Comment: @Michael I didn't say he did, I was just wondering

Comment: @Tommy He doesn't want to know if his list is empty, but if adding/removing to the list is allowed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207162/fixed-size-list-in-java Check this.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  It is not valuable to know if you can add or delete elements from a list.  Either assume that you can and accept an exception or assume that you cant.

Comment: I actually don't think there is a 100% sure way to check if the List is of fixed size. But just to throw the idea out there: You could use reflection to check if the list implementation overrides the add/remove methods or just uses the ones from the AbstractList. `boolean addNotSupported = (java.util.AbstractList.class==list.getClass().getMethod("add", Object.class).getDeclaringClass());`

Comment: It is kind of odd to have a code path that has special treatment for a read-only list if the code intends to insert. Perhaps the OP can explain what *he's really trying to do* and why he needs to support read-only lists simultaneously with lists that can be updated.

Comment: This is a significant code smell.  Better to just e.g. _always_ copy to an `ArrayList` or the like.

Comment: I can think of a scenario where this would be useful: when you want to have a precondition check at the start of a method. That would not be a code smell.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Good API design remains a foreign concept to the Java world.

Answer (score 13):

A list created from a `String[]` by

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

will have `Arrays` as enclosing class, while one created by for example `new ArrayList()` won't have the enclosing class. So the following should work to check if the List was produced as a result of calling `Arrays.toList()`:

```
static <T> boolean wasListProducedAsAResultOfCallingTheFunctionArrays_asList(List<T> l) {
    return Arrays.class.equals(l.getClass().getEnclosingClass());
}
```

Beware that this method relies on undocumented behavior. It will break if they added another nested List subclass to the Arrays class.

Comment: Good one. `isFixedSize` is a bit of misnomer for that function, though.

Comment: @Michael thanks. Do you have a better name in mind? Feel free to edit :-)

Comment: [maybe `wasListProducedAsAResultOfCallingTheFunctionArrays_asList`](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)??

Comment: @Michael  Took it :D

Comment: Just a code style suggestion... Remove the or and just use `Arrays.class.equals(l.getClass().getEnclosingClass())`. Or just `Arrays.class == l.getClass().getEnclosingClass()`

Comment: Good suggestion @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, didn't think about that when I wrote it earlier.

Comment: This fails to return true for wrappers around the base list, such as `Collections.checkedList`, `Collections.synchronizedList` or `Collections.unmodifiableList`. It also fails to return true for `Arrays.asList().subList` or other types of fixed-size list like `Collections.emptyList` or `Collections.singletonList`, or other immutable lists from other utility libraries.

Comment: @Boann Or for short: It does *only* what the (updated) method name suggests - and not what the question originally was about...

Comment: this test would fail for java-9 immutable collections

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to find out if some list is fixed size or not?

In theory - No.  Fixed sizedness is an emergent property of the implementation of a list class.  You can only determine if a list has that property  by trying to add an element.

And note that a simple behavioral test would not reliably distinguish between a fixed sized list and a bounded list or a list that was permanently or *temporarily* read-only.

---

In practice, a fixed sized list will *typically* have a different class to an ordinary one.  You can test the class of an object to see if it or isn't a specific class.  So if you understand what classes *would be* used to implement fixed sized lists *in your code-base*, then you can test if a specific list is fixed sized.

For example the `Arrays.asList(...)` method returns a `List` object whose actual class is `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`.  That is a private nested class, but you could use reflection find it, and then use `Object.getClass().equals(...)` to test for it.

However, this approach is fragile.  Your code could break if the implementation of `Arrays` was modified, or if you started using other forms of fixed sized list as well.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The List API is identical regardless of whether a List is expandable or not, something that was [deliberate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657191/why-did-they-decide-to-make-interfaces-have-optional-operations).

There is also nothing in the List API that allows you to query it to determine this feature.

You can't completely reliably determine this information by reflection, because you will be depending on internal details of the implementation, and because there is an unbounded number of classes that are potentially fixed-size. For example, in addition to [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-), there is also [`Arrays.asList().subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-), which happens to return a different class. There can also be wrappers around the base list like [`Collections.checkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedList-java.util.List-java.lang.Class-), [`Collections.synchronizedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) and [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-). There are also other fixed-size lists: [`Collections.emptyList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList--), [`Collections.singletonList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-), and [`Collections.nCopies`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies-int-T-). Outside the standard library, there are things like Guava's [`ImmutableList`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html). It's also pretty trivial to hand-roll a list for something by extending [`AbstractList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) (for a fixed-size list you need only implement the `size()` and `get(int)` methods).

Even if you detect that your list is not fixed-size, the specification of [`List.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) allows it to refuse elements for other reasons. For example, `Collections.checkedList` wrappers throw a `ClassCastException` for elements of unwanted type.

And even if you know your list is expandable, and allows arbitrary elements, that doesn't mean you want to use it. Perhaps it's synchronized, or not synchronized, or isn't serializable, or it's a slow linked list, or has some other quality that you don't want.

If you want control over the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the list, or you want to be sure that no other code has kept a reference to it, the practice is that you create a new one yourself. It's not expensive to do so when unnecessary (memcopies are blazing fast), and it lets you reason more definitely about your code will actually do at runtime. If you'd really like to avoid creating unnecessary copies, try *whitelisting* instead of blacklisting list classes. For example:

```
if (list.getClass() != ArrayList.class) {
    list = new ArrayList<>(list);
}
```

(Note: That uses `getClass` instead of `instanceof`, because `instanceof` would also be true for any weird subclasses of `ArrayList`.)

Comment: Fantastic answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are immutable collections in java-9, but there is still no common `@Immutable` annotation for example or a common marker interface that we could query to get this information.

The simplest way I can think of would be simply to get the name of the class of such an instance:

```
String nameList = List.of(1, 2, 3).getClass().getName();
System.out.println(nameList.contains("Immutable"));
```

but that still relies on internal details, since it queries the name of the common class `ImmutableCollections`, that is not public and obviously can change without notice.