# How to know if a List object has a fixed size

Tags: java

How can I know if a List has a fixed size?

```
List<String> fixed = Arrays.asList(new String[100]);
```

This will create a fixed List. but the instantiated array of String object is not referenced to the String array anymore.

Comment: A list doesn't have a fixed size, only a current size

Comment: When I try `Arrays.asList("a").getClass()`, it returns `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`. This implementation may probably change. But maybe checking the class could help...? Otherwise, the `List` interface doesn't have a method for that.

Comment: Why do you want to know this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm practicing for OCA exam. and I just thought about what if's

Comment: You cannot determine that. Its `List` implementation dependent.

Comment: just an idea:
 boolean isFixed=false;
        List<String> fixed = Arrays.asList(new String[100]);
        try {
            String test="test";
            fixed.add(test);
            fixed.remove(test);
        }catch (Exception e){
            isFixed=true;
        }

Comment: thanks for the inputs guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref: [Is it possible to find out if some list is fixed size or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975443/is-it-possible-to-find-out-if-some-list-is-fixed-size-or-not/44975935)

**Is it possible to find out if some list is fixed size or not?**

In theory - No. Fixed sizedness is an emergent property of the implementation of a list class. You can only determine if a list has that property by trying to add an element.

And note that a simple behavioral test would not reliably distinguish between a fixed sized list and a bounded list or a list that was permanently or temporarily read-only.

In practice, a fixed sized list will typically have a different class to an ordinary one. You can test the class of an object to see if it or isn't a specific class. So if you understand what classes would be used to implement fixed sized lists in your code-base, then you can test if a specific list is fixed sized.

For example the `Arrays.asList(...)` method returns a List object whose actual class is java.util.Arrays.ArrayList. That is a private nested class, but you could use reflection find it, and then use `Object.getClass().equals(...)` to test for it.

However, this approach is fragile. Your code could break if the implementation of Arrays was modified, or if you started using other forms of fixed sized list as well.

Answer (score -5):

you can  use Set,Set can enter unlimited object

Comment: This does not answer the question, nor is it an answer at all. It would be a comment. Please wait until you have enough reputation to give [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: it's also not correct. a Set can contain a lot of objects, but it's limited by the resources of the environment, and by the implementation of Java itself. same goes for a List, btw